# make turtles start from a random position in unbounded world (random walk 360)

Tags: random, netlogo

I'm working with the Random Walk 360 model from the Library and simply trying out to make the turtles start from random position instead of (0,0). But somehow it doesn't work. I'm guessing it is related to the part of the code allowing the world to be unbounded:

```
set xc xc + (step-size * dx)
set yc yc + (step-size * dy)
; hide turtles who have moved out of the world
ifelse patch-at (xc - xcor) (yc - ycor) = nobody
 [ ht ]
 [ st
   set xcor xc
   set ycor yc ]
```

But still cannot figure how to adapt this code so that turtles start from random position.
Any help would be welcome,
Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 2):

Change this line in the `setup` procedure:

```
crt num-turtles
```

To:

```
crt num-turtles [
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  set xc xcor
  set yc ycor
]
```

Probably you weren't setting `xc` and `yc`? In this model, those are variables that hold the turtle's true position on the infinite plane. It isn't enough to just set `xcor` and `ycor`, which only represent the turtle's position within the world boundaries.